# pinterest social tracking with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, pinterest

I need to track a pinterest button in google analytics. The first code works for an html website implimented after the pinterest button code that is wrapped in a pin div. I am trying to apply it to the second code below which is part of an array of social media buttons. I can not get it to work however. Any help would be appreciated.
I am on my phone. Ill post the full code later, just wanted to throw this out there.

```
    <div class="pin"><a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.myurl.com/testingjava.html" class="pin-it-button">Pin It</a></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('div.pin').click(function() {
                     _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'Pinterest', 'pin', $(location).attr('href')]);
                });
        });
        </script>



    'script' => '
    <div class="pin"><a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=###URL###"        class="pin-it-button" count-layout="###layout###">Pin It</a></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js">           </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $(\'div.pin\').click(function() {
            _gaq.push([\'_trackSocial\', \'Pinterest\', \'pin\', $(location).attr(\'href\')]);
            });
    }); 
    </script>',
```

Comment: this is the full code i used in the plugin that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The opening script tag is not closed:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(\'div.pin\').click(function() {
        _gaq.push([\'_trackSocial\', \'Pinterest\', \'pin\', $(location).attr(\'href\')]);
        });
}); 
</script>',
```

Comment: that was just a mistyping when i put it in here. it is closed on all my implementations.

Comment: it is inside of a php plugin if that changes anything

Comment: This is of interest to me also. I've done it with Facebook, Google+, and Twitter, but never with Pinterest. There are plugins that can help but if you have static HTML or some custom system you need this trick in the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [tutorial or at least an explination](http://blog.muschamp.ca/2013/10/02/tracking-social-media-button-clicks-in-google-analytics/) on how I tracked Pinterest, Google+, Facebook, and Twitter on an old HTML page using Google Analytics, I've used the same basic techniques on my favourite quotation mashup and even on my current employer's latest campaign page.

Basically jQuery is used to add in the event, this isn't a technique, other people thought of it first, but getting all four to work together is more work, plus I did the proper structured metadata etc. etc.